# Trying to get class/id value on tabbed Panel tab section

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

For test automation purposes, I need a class/id value on the tab bit (whatever you call it..) in a tabbed pane.

[image]

I have tried the following **AAA**,**BBB**,**CCC** and **DDD**, and none of these appear in the class in the DOM level.

```
var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel');
panel1.cls = 'AAA'
panel1.itemCls = 'BBBB'
var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel');

Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        cls:'CCC',
        itemCls:'DDD',
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [panel1,panel2]
    }
);
```

I know its somehow possible. Anyone have an idea??

http://jsfiddle.net/GQULg/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK just figured this out. I need to set a tabConfig object on the panel or container that goes inside the tabbed panel.

```
var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel');
panel1.tabConfig = {
    cls: 'myTab'
};
```

The tabConfig object holds the cls (class values) that will populate the tabs on the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use selenium: other people stated that selenium uses plain JavaScript commands and that best would be to also use Ext.getCmp(), Ext.ComponentQuery()... from selenium.

Why? Because it does not need any special changes to your production code!